# Uploading image using express.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, form-data, body-parser

I am trying to upload an image using Express.js. I am submitting a post request with form-data, that contains an image. [image]

Here is my server.js file. I understand that body parser is unable to handle form data. My question is if I can use another middleware such as busboy, or multer in order to handle form data for certain routes, while keeping body parser for others? All of my existing routes are using body parser and I don't want to break my backend by completely replacing body-parser.

```js
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { join } = require("path");

//routes 
const accountsRouter = require('./routes/accounts');
const betsRouter = require('./routes/bets');
const contestsRouter = require('./routes/contests');
const fixturesRouter = require('./routes/fixtures');
const leaguesRouter = require('./routes/leagues');
const sportsRouter = require('./routes/sports');
const postsRouter = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "*"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});


app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "build")));

//use routes 
app.use('/accounts', accountsRouter);
app.use('/bets', betsRouter);
app.use('/contests', contestsRouter);
app.use('/fixtures', fixturesRouter);
app.use('/leagues', leaguesRouter);
app.use('/sports', sportsRouter);
app.use('/posts', postsRouter);

module.exports = app;
```